# ASP.NET MVC Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, selectedvalue

I am making some changes to already existing ASP.NET MVC 1 app where there is a form with a dropdown list that has all 50 states hard coded into the HTML.  After filling out the form the user can later go back and edit their information.  I want to make it so that on the edit screen the value that is already in the DB gets the "selected" attribute for the state.  The only way I can think to do this is to build the html on the server and send it down to the view, is there a better practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, View is the only place where you should generate the markup.

My suggestion is to write a JavaScript snippet like this:

```
 $(function(){ 
     $('#dropDownId').val(@Model.SelectedValue);
 });
```

It's effective, easy, maintainable, and of course, fast.